# Custom row list shape overrides selector state color

Tags: android

I've the list view where i created a custom shape to make the rounded corners. As i added selector code along to it,state pressed doesn't works what i expected. Actually, the state pressed color was shown out of the custom row list. i.e it shows the color at the end of each corner. How should i solve this?

This is my `feed_list` layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
     >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" 
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom row layout `list_item` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customshape"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textColor="#7F7F7F"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`list_selector` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 

     android:drawable="@drawable/bg_yellow_dark_round"/>


</selector>
```

`bg_yellow_dark_round`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#AC7E00" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#AC7E00" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

`customshape` (for rounded corner)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
           android:shape="rectangle">

         <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"


      android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#006699" />

    <solid android:color="#fff"/>

</shape>
```

If i remove the `android:background="@drawable/customshape"` in `list_item`, it works. But, i need rounded corner along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why your list selector is inside the list view and not inside list_item , If i understand you you wwnt list view that all it corners are rounded.
and inside the listview each chile you click will has a selector, Right?
If so you will have yo put your customshape on the listview and the list_selector on the listItem.

Comment: It just makes the rounded corner for the entire list view not each list item. But, selector works.